# CakePHP: saving file with new record with FileUpload plugin

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to use the `FileUpload` plugin (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin) in my CakePHP (1.3) app.

I have two models: `PendingContract` and `PendingContractFile`. A `PendingContract` can have many `PendingContractFile` records. When saving a new `PendingContract`, I'd also like to save the uploaded `PendingContractFile`; however, my save method fails because `PendingContract` does not yet have an ID, and that is used as the foreign key in my `PendingContractFile`.

For clarity, here are my models:

```
<?php
class PendingContract extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'PendingContract';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Supplier'
    );
    var $hasMany = array(
        'PendingContractFile'
    );
}

class PendingContractFile extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'PendingContractFile';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'PendingContract' => array(
            'className' => 'PendingContract',
            'foreignKey' => 'pending_contract_id'
        ),
        'Author' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'author_id'
        )
    );
}
```

And here is my controller method where I'm saving my `PendingContract`:

```
<?php
class PendingContractsController extends AppController {

    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->FileUpload->success) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Pending contract successfully created.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash($this->FileUpload->showErrors());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the error I'm getting is:

> 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (pending_contract_files, CONSTRAINT pending_contract_files_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pending_contract_id) REFERENCES pending_contracts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

How can I use the `FileUpload` plugin so that it attaches the uploaded file with my new `PendingContract` record?

Comment: It looks like the `insert` is failing because either the Author or the PendingContract record isn't being saved beforehand. Both of those foreign keys must be present when inserting; my guess is that one or both of them are missing.

Comment: @inkedmn I've identified the problem. I just wondered if any one has had the same problem and if so, what solution they arrived at.

Comment: It is not clear how you are saving your data based on the code you pasted

Comment: The above is what I've managed to deduce from the docs (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin) but it really is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey] = String::uuid();
    }
    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

This will generate a new UUID for the record before save. You should probably only do this if the key is not already set.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the plugin, at it doesn't appear that it will save posted data along with uploaded files. It purposefully separates upload file data from any other input in the form and performs a save for each file.

Personally I would try other plugins such as https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload which do not rely in any controller-level code.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem, what i did is unset the validation when adding a new PendingContractFile in your case. So before the saveAll method try adding:

```
unset($this->PendingContract->PendingContractFile->validate['pending_contract_id']);
```

so it wont check for the foreign_key.
hope it helps.